# Inherit purchase order and create new object

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, openerp-8, odoo-10

[image]

> Blockquote

I inherit the _inherit='purchase.order, and create new object with name _name='job.order' and use its view but when i am going to save it showing error (odoo warning) in pic.

Comment: what you want to accomplish ???!

Comment: I want use purchase order as a  work order in my module but dont want its effect in purchase so i create a new object and inherit purchase.order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use _inherits instead of _inherit this way you will create new object with with all field of 'purchase.order plus new field you declare in your model that won't affect original model.

> for reference check res.user model in base module